# Laravel check query count value

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

I Have the following query in my app,

```
public function ExcOrders($driver_id, $from_date, $to_date){

        $orders = DB::table('order_details as o')
                    ->join('order_tracker as a','o.id','=','a.oid')
                    ->where('a.owner_id','=',$driver_id)
                    ->whereBetween('a.created_at',[$from_date, $to_date]) 
                    ->where('o.status',0)
                    ->select([DB::raw('SUM(o.price) as TotalDeposits'),DB::raw('count(o.price) as count')])
                    ->get();

        if($orders->count() > 0){
            return response()->json(['status_code'=>1000,'data'=>$orders , 'message'=>"null"],200);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['status_code'=>2000,'data'=>null , 'message'=>"You Have No Orders For Now !"],200);
        }
    }
```

And its working fine, and return the required result but my issue as shown in return i need to check if the count value is larger than zero and I can't

The result is always like below,

```
{
    "status_code": 1000,
    "data": [
        {
            "TotalDeposits": null,
            "count": 0
        }
    ],
    "message": "null"
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: you are using `->get();` which means there may be several results. If it is multiple, how will you decide whether the `count > 0` - at least one of them ? all of them ?

Comment: @Ersoy the result are only TotalDeposits and count, i need to check the count value

Comment: So you are returning one result, no need to use get then - i am posting as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public function ExcOrders($driver_id, $from_date, $to_date)
{
    $orders = DB::table('order_details as o')
        ->join('order_tracker as a', 'o.id', '=', 'a.oid')
        ->where('a.owner_id', '=', $driver_id)
        ->whereBetween('a.created_at', [$from_date, $to_date])
        ->where('o.status', 0)
        ->select([DB::raw('SUM(o.price) as TotalDeposits'), DB::raw('count(o.price) as count')])
        ->first(); //replaced get here 

    if ($orders->count > 0) { // check here - if you need you may check $orders first too 
        return response()->json(['status_code' => 1000, 'data' => $orders, 'message' => "null"], 200);
    }

    return response()->json(['status_code' => 2000, 'data' => null, 'message' => "You Have No Orders For Now !"], 200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but Im not getting 1 raw result !, I need the query to get the sum and the count for all the conditions matching raws , please check my output how i can get the count value thats all what I need

Comment: @AliAdil if your response is array, but there is only one element in it(everytime) then you don't need to get it as array. If it is array but there are multiple objects consist of {totalDeposits and count} then how would you decide `the count > 0`. Since some of them may be zero some of them maybe greater than zero.

Comment: Just to make all things clear, but as i know the first() function will select only the first raw which will match the query ?! and in my case i have several raws

Comment: okay so i can't use it in my case cause as i mentioned i have several raws and thus i have to use get()

Comment: Lets say this is the response `[{"TotalDeposits": null,"count": 0}, {"TotalDeposits": 2,"count": 2}, {"TotalDeposits": 1,"count": 1}]` there are two rows > 0 and 1 row is 0 - how do you want to make comparison and what will be the decision ? `at least one row with the value > 0 ` or `all the rows > 0` or something else @AliAdil

Comment: yes and as I mentioned the condition is active only when the returned count value is > 0 so I think I don't have any other solution but to loop through the query result $orders and get the count value

Comment: actually you may use `having` statement in your query. it will return the results if the having statement works such as `->having('count', '>', 0)` please check here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods @AliAdil

Comment: @AliAdil this will filter rows if they satisfy the count conditions. zeros will be eliminated. if it doesn't fit to your case, you may proceed as iterating. Best

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$orders = $orders->reject(function ($order) {
    // do somthing ...
    return $order->data->count >= 'some condition you like';
})
->map(function ($order) {
    // do somthing ...
    return $order;
});
```